# Where do software strategy questions go?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I often don't know where to ask a question on stackoverflow.com

Currently, I have a repository that I want to divide into two and have GitHub pages ( static only ) host my Front-End and have Heroku host my Back-End ( node server ).

I was going to ask if there is a strategy for managing two repositories for one site.

Where would I ask this question?

I consider this a conceptual strategy question not a coding question.

Comment: Wherever you ask this, you'll need a more precise question than just "strategy".

Comment: Ask it on Meta disguised as a question about where to ask it.